# How to use the name property in production

Tags: sencha-touch-2, production, senchatouch-2.4

I've created my own control to use for every day of the week and I used the name property so the control knows for which day it's used. On the initialize of the control I use the name property for calling tap events, but for some reason that name property is unidentified in minified code, it works fine in normal mode.

So is there something about production mode in Sencha Touch that makes it hard to use the name property.

Use of the name property:

```
{
  xtype: 'mycontrol',
  name: 'monday'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience there are some things that don't work for targeting elements in a production build. I found that out the hard way with `action: 'someAction'` with buttons.

`name` is best used along with `field` components.

I used name to assign a form field to a model fieldname. so when I use a `formpanel` it's easy to use `getValues()` on the form and each field value will automatically know where it belongs.

I would suggest using `itemId: 'saturday'` or `cls: 'saturday'` depending on your situation.